# Visual Studio, vcpkg available in vs but not as an admin

Tags: visual-studio

I wrote a program in VS19 and it includes all the libraries which I installed using vcpkg,
But when I open VS as an admin, this doesn´t work and I can´t find vcpkg.
I the first photo you can see the "normal" VS and in the second when I open it as an admin. Sorry it is in german but I think it is clear what I mean. This is seen in the configuration menu of the project.
[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dgBX.png) [admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eed4m.png)
I suppose that I have to enable it somewhere but I can´t find it.